# How to fix Type error cannot destructure property "app_Id" of undefined or null

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Virgil security with firebase, and I have integrated it with cloud functions. When I register a user in my app, it's suppose to trigger a user verification to register the user to Virgil cloud, but instead, I get this type error when I check the cloud functions console cannot destructure property "app_Id" of undefined or null. Meanwhile, I have the .env from Virgil security documentation in my root project.

**This is the screenshot of the error on the console**

[image: 1]

Comment: It seems like your .env file is not being read. Were you able to use other secret keys?

Comment: No, I just keep getting this error on registration